# notifyDataSetChanged in viewHolder class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

Can I use notifyDataSetChanged() in view Holder?

```
class ItemViewHolder(context: Context?, view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

       func update(){
           // ...
           // i need to update adapter for example
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
       }

}
```

Comment: Yes you can .. even without `adapter` object if your viewHolder is an Inner class and `update()` is getting called on some action . Whats the issue you are facing ?

Comment: @ADM I don't like pass adapter to inner view holder.

Comment: You don't Have to .. Just let `ItemViewHolder` be a Inner Class of Adapter class.

Answer (score 5):

Turning your `class` into an `inner class` is certainly one approach.  I would also consider handing your `ViewHolder` a reference to a `Listener` or `Callback` interface that you come up with (or a set of functions) as well.  This would make refactoring easier, if you ever decided to move your ViewHolder to a different file or outside of your adapter otherwise.  It also better respects the Single Responsibility Principle, as we remove data-management from our ViewHolder and let that happen elsewhere.

For example:

```
class ViewHolder(
    private itemView: View
    private val onDataSetChanged: () -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun onUpdate() {
        // Perform changes...
        onDataSetChanged()
    }

}
```

It is a bit strange to me though that a ViewHolder would be manipulating data items like this.  Generally, these only hold onto the item's positional information and view-state, not the item itself.  Another approach might be to pass positional information to the update lambda:

```
class ViewHolder(
    private itemView: View
    private val onDataSetChanged: (Int) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun onShouldUpdate() {
        if (adapterPosition == RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) return
        onDataSetChanged(adapterPosition)
    }

}
```

And then handle that update elsewhere.  For example, in either the Adapter, or the ViewModel logic:

```
fun onCreateViewHolder(...) {
    val viewHolder = ViewHolder(...) { /* do update */ }
}
```

This leaves us at a point where now the Adapter is responsible for both mapping data to views as well as managing that data's state... and that's not very clean.

Here's how I like to do it:

```
class Adapter(private val updateItem: (Item) -> Unit) {
    fun onCreateViewHolder(...) {
        return ViewHolder(...) { updateItem(items[it]) }
    }
}
```

Where we handle data manipulations in a more reasonable place. Here:

1. The ViewHolder maps a click or update event to the position of the item it is holding
2. The Adapter maps a position to an actual data item
3. The Presentation object (such as an Architecture Components ViewModel) (whomever provides the lambda to the adapter) performs the manipulation. (More on this coming below)

In this case, your notifyDataSetChanged would be handled instead by the presenter then feeding back into the Adapter.  Perhaps, for example, you have a method on Adapter called `setData(items: List<Item>)`.  When a new list of items is available, the presenter notifies the adapter, which sets the items:

```
// In your adapter
fun setData(newItems: List<Item>) {
    val oldItems = items
    items = newItems
    notifyDataSetChanged()
    // Alternatively, utilize DiffUtil
}
```

Your ViewModel could then expose an observable field, perhaps utilizing `LiveData`.

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val items: LiveData<List<Item>>
    fun updateItem(item: Item) { ... }
}
```

Your Activity, where you set up your adapter, could then observe changes to this:

```
val adapter = Adapter(viewModel::updateItem)

// Note you could probably use a method reference instead of a lambda.
viewModel.items.observe(this) { adapter.setItems(it) }
```

I hope that sort of helps to outline the approach.  I could talk all day about this, so feel free to ask any questions about this.  The idea here is that we're clearly separating our concerns (SRP), removing the need to hand the entire adapter to the ViewHolder (ISP), and leveraging lambdas to make sure we're not directly depending on things we don't need to be (DIP).

Answer (score 1):

Implement a onclick event listener in your View Holder and then delete a view holder like this.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = v.getId();
            switch (id) {
                case R.id.musicPlay:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setType("audio/*");
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(mItem.getContentUri()));
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.musicShare:

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Music is shared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.musicDelete:
                    if (context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse(mItem.getContentUri()), null, null)>0)
                        Toast.makeText(context, mItem.getTitle() + " is deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{

                                    mItem.getData()},

                            null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                    mValues.remove(mItem);
                                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }

                            });
                    break;
            }
        }
```